# how to select greatest number from column 2 according to value of column 1 bash script-sed-awk

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a file like this:

```
1 12:00

1 12:34

1 01:01

1 08:06

2 09:56

2 06:52
...
```

and I want to select from each value of first column the greatest value of the second one.

New file:

```
1 12:34

2 09:56 
...
```

How can I do this?? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '
  { if ($2>values[$1]) values[$1]=$2; }
  END {
    for (i in values) {
      print i,values[i]
    }
  }
' file
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
sort -k1,1n -k2,2r file | sort -uk1,1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -nale '$F[1]=~s/://;$h{$F[0]}=$F[1]if($F[1]>$h{$F[0]}); 
     END{for(sort keys(%h)){($x=$h{$_})=~s/^(..)(..)$/\1:\2/;print"$_ $x"}}' file
```

[See it](http://ideone.com/d0DpD)

Answer (score 0):

Bash only;

```
# build arrays with 1.column value in its name
# use all digits in the row as index, the row as value
while read a b ; do
  eval "array$a[$a${b//:/}]=\"$a $b\""
done < "$infile"

# select the last element of each array
for name in ${!array*}; do
  last='${'${name}'[-1]}'
  eval "echo ${last}"
done
```